# Lebesgue outer measure intervals may all be assumed to be open

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

On page 6-7 of *Invitation to Ergodic Theory* by C. E. Silva

**Proposition 2.1.1** Lebesgue outer measure satisfies the following properties.

(1) The interval $I_j$ in the definition of outer measure may all be assumed to be open.

**With the proof for (1) being**:

Let $\alpha(A)$ denote the outer measure of $A$ when computed using only open bounded intervals in the covering. Clearly, $\lambda^*(A)\leq\alpha(A).$

I don't understand why $\lambda^*(A)\leq\alpha(A)$ is true as a closed interval $I_k$ being $[a, b]$ contains $(a,b)$.

**edit:**

Following that snippet. The book says:

Now for $\epsilon>0$. For any covering ${I_j}$ of $A$ let $K_j$ be an open interval containing $I_j$ such that $\mid K_j\mid < \mid I_j\mid + \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}, j\geq1$. Then 
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mid K_j\mid<\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mid I_j\mid+\epsilon$$

Taking the infimum of each side gives $\alpha(A)\leq\lambda^*(A)+\epsilon$, as this holds for all $\epsilon$, $\alpha(A)\leq\lambda^*(A)$.

Comment: Replace $[a_n,b_n]$ by $(a_n-\epsilon/2^n,b_n+\epsilon/2^n)$.

Comment: Is $\lambda^*(A)$ defined as the infimum over covers of $A$ by closed intervals?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry, I left out the proof going the other direction. So I believe the interval $(a_n - \epsilon/2^n, b_n + \epsilon/2^n)$ is for the second part of the proof.

Comment: @Brahadeesh yes you're correct $\lambda*(A)$ is defined as the infimum of bounded covers.

Comment: Then you allow both closed as well as open intervals to cover the set $A$ when taking the infimum, isn't it? Then, as Martin's answer says, if you take an infimum over covers by a lesser number of sets then the infimum is possibly larger, that is, $\lambda^*(A) \leq \alpha(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

The outer measure is defined as an infimum. If you take the infimum over less sets (only the open ones) then the infimum is possibly greater.